# Обновление данных при нажатии кнопки

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, python-3.8

Есть форма логин пароль и две кнопки. При нажатии на кнопку "submit" происходит авторизация, поиск и вывод нужных данных.

**.py**

```
class form1(Widget):
    def submit(self):
        user = self.ids["login"].text
        passw = self.ids["passw"].text
        result = requests.get('http://1.2.3.4',auth=HTTPDigestAuth(user, passw))
        match_pattern = r"status"
        match = re.search(match_pattern, result.text)
        if match:
           self.ids.output_label.text = f"Статус:{match.group(1)}"
    def refresh(self):
        submit()

class test(App):
    def build(self):
        return form1()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test().run()
```

**.kv**

```
<form1>
    BoxLayout:
        padding:10
        orientation:'horizontal' 
        size_hint:(1,1)
        Label:
            id: output_label
            text: ""
            font_size:22
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        size_hint:(1,1)
        TextInput:
            id: login
            hint_text:"Username"
        TextInput:
            id: passw
            password: True
            hint_text:"Password"
        Button:
            text: "Submit"
            on_release: root.submit()
        Button:
            text: "Refresh"
            on_release: root.refresh()
```

Каким должен быть обработчик второй кнопки чтобы повторно не вводя логин\пароль обновить вывод.

Comment: А `GUI` у вас на чём, какая библиотека? Добавьте соответствующий тег.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.